# React Native App Play Store JavascriptException

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, facebook, crash

I have a React Native app on the Play Store but it is crashing for some devices 1000s of times in the past month. I've never encountered this crash using my own device or the emulator. I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.

I have Pro Guard and Hermes enabled, here is the stack trace I get when I go to the Crashes and ANRs section under Google Play Console.

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:1025689
anonymous@1:502947
value@1:55572
value@1:65672
anonymous@1:64155
value@1:65118
value@1:64113

at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:147)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:21)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (Unknown Source:37)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native source map of hermes bundle with firebase crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835466/react-native-source-map-of-hermes-bundle-with-firebase-crashlytics)

Comment: did u find any reason ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this after digging around the React Native documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/symbolication.

I was able to generate a more human readable stack trace by copying the above stack trace into a txt file and then running the command: `npx metro-symbolicate android/app/build/generated/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.map < stacktrace.txt`.

Comment: what was the reason ?